# How to save images within texts like medium blog post

Tags: database, image, architecture

I'm considering creating a blog website like medium.com where the writer can place images within the post body, just like the below image or like this question, the text, the image, and then text again.

[image]

I'm aware that images can be converted base64 and save right into the database column. But I don't think it is efficient.

I can't think of the system architecture that supports the images are preserved their orders as the writer put in.

I'm going to use React.js and Spring boot.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @AdrianK I've updated the question. Please kindly see it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be confusing images and image tags (in the markup/HTML).

When people see content in a browser, the content is simply some kind of markup language like HTML, which the browser interprets and renders (displays).

Markup, such as HTML, is of course text based and easily saved in a database table.
In HTML, images are not part of the markup, they are simply another tag which **references** the image the browser should render, like this:

```
<img src='/localfolder/profilephoto.png'>
<img src='https://morphological.files.wordpress.com/2016/08/example.png'>
```

The images that the image tags reference can be anywhere - in a local folder on your website, or somewhere totally different - as long as the location is accessible to the users who will eventually read it.

When you see blog posts like on Medium, and you think about how those are edited, all the author does is create and modify markup; that can markup can include image tags, which can be moved about with no restriction.

When the blog post is saved, the markup (text) is saved to the database - that's it.

As part of the editing process, the images are usually uploaded separately beforehand, so that the author can more easily insert them into the blog post during the editing process, so that they can see what the post looks like.

In my (dated) experience of web development, images are simply saved as image files somewhere, not converted to Base64 by any part of my application code.